# How to kick users from Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, users, maintenance

I need to migrate some databases from one server to another to decommission the first one. This server is sharing a network share and a database. Prior to migration and to ensure data integrity, I need to avoid users connections to DB as well as network resources. How can I kick all users connections (and keep them disconnected) but administrator ones?.

Both servers are now DC in case this is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can prevent new user connection using firewall(do not forget to leave an exception for administrator).
2. Than you can close RDP sessions using `logoff` or `tskill` commands
3. Than you can close opened smb sessions using `net session \\<computer> /delete`

Answer (score 7):

For the database you could issue these commands providing the accounts connecting to the database do not have db_owner privileges:

```
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
go
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET ONLINE
go
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET RESTRICTED_USER
GO
```

To log off any users connected via RDP you could query the connected users using:

```
quser
```

...and a logoff with the listed IDs to logoff any connected user:

```
logoff <ID>
```

You can then disconnect any open smb sessions with:

```
net sessions \\<computer> /delete
```

I would then access the share permissions and remove any permissions after creating a screen shot of the settings. This will prevent new connections.